# How to switch from Mobile "Classic" to "Contemporary" View in SharePoint Mobile View

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, mobile

I have activated the `Mobile` feature to make the SharePoint site much better in mobile experience, however when I open the site and with Google Chrome "in my server" and I select the mobile view I get the following result:

[image]

which is the `Contemporary` View, and it is wonderful. But when I open the site from my `Local PC`, I get the following result:

[image]

which is the `Classic` View.

Now, how can I switch from `Classic` to `Contemporary` View?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `chrome browser`. Hit developer tools and change as below

> Application tab->Cookies->'Select you webapp'->Change **Mobile from '1' to '0'**.

Again, if you want to view in mobileview **toggle device toolbar** and refresh the page.

---

**Switch to PC View**   This changes the display from mobile browser view to a full desktop view of a site. This command is available in both contemporary and classic views in SharePoint Server 2013. You can switch back to the mobile browser view in Site Settings. Under the Site Information section, click the URL under the **Mobile Site** URL heading. - [Took from MSDN article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161351.aspx)

Comment: this only switches from desktop view into mobile view, but I want to switch from classic mobile view into Contemporary mobile view

Comment: Updated my answer from MSDN site.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161351.aspx

Comment: But how to switch from moblie classic into mobile contemporary ?